# Minimalistic text editor/document processor?

Tags: editors, word-processing

I am looking for an open source word processor that can do the following:

- Text size
- Access a font database
- Big font/cursive
- Tables
- List
- Non-analogue imitation

Comment: WYSIWYG or no? (Your favorite text editor) + (*TeX) is the One True Way, but not WYSIWYG

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the default OpenOffice word processor? It works well with most things, though I'm not sure about that last requirement.

Comment: Its not very minimalistic